# Rails 3: PostgreSQL access denied after renaming app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.1

I just renamed my application (replacing all instances of the old name with the new one), and now my application can no longer connect to the postgres database running on localhost.

```
PG::Error (could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any ideas?

Thanks :-----)

EDIT: This is my database.yml

```
common: &common
  adapter: postgresql
  username: <username>
  password: <password>

development:
  <<: *common
  database: development

test:
  <<: *common
  database: test

production:
  <<: *common
  database: production
```

Where username and password are the username and credentials for my postgres installation. However, I can't connect to the server using pgAdmin either!

Comment: can you post your database.yml file and also did you try to rename it to older name and check if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: Apparently my postgres server wasn't running locally, so I had to manually start the Service. :-)